# Using Lists in a C# application through Boo

Tags: c#, list, embed, boo

```
import EternalDungeon
import System.Collections

static def PlayerActivate():
    for x in range(ED.Mobs.Count):
        if ED.Mobs(x).Pos == ED.player.SpaceInFront():
            ED.Mobs(x).OnHit(ED.Sword)
            break
```

When this is compiled, I get the error

`BCE0077: It's not possible to invoke an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[[EternalDungeon.Mob, Eternal Dungeon, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]`

At (6,15) and (7,16). In C# I include assemblies like so, which is probably wrong and wierd:

```
        compiler.Parameters.References.Add(Assembly.LoadFile(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Eternal Dungeon.exe";));
        compiler.Parameters.References.Add(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(System.Collections.Comparer)));
```

Any help is appreciated, and I'm rather new to both Boo and 'Assemblies'. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem myself, I confused lists for arrays,

```
    if ED.Mobs(x).Pos == ED.player.SpaceInFront():
```

Changes to

```
    if ED.Mobs[x].Pos == ED.player.SpaceInFront():
```